# Testing if the hyperlinks in the body of an action mailer resolve in Rails minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Is there a way to test (in MiniTest) if the hyperlinks in the body of a rails ActionMailer point to a location with a 3xx or a 2xx response?

If not, is there a way to test that a view helper method is outputting a link that works?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an integration test. You can do it easily with MiniTest by doing a request for that page and see what response is returned. I would not trust just a 2xx or 3xx code though. Yes the link works, but do you want to know that the expected action from the link happened?

I use something like this for a password reset link:

```
require 'test_helper'
include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Integration

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

test "it should send a password reset" do
    get new_password_reset_path(email: User.first.email)
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

But I like to know that the link actually produced the correct page. My password reset page actually produces a 3xx code of :redirect. So I assert that the `:found` response was received, then follow the redirect and check for the message that confirms that the password email was requested to be sent (realize that if your actual mailer may not be working if you do this in a delayed job and are not set up to receive an error response immediately).

So I do something like this:

```
require 'test_helper'
include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Integration

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

test "it should send a password reset" do
    get new_password_reset_path(email: User.first.email)
    assert_response :found
    follow_redirect!
    assert_includes @response.body, 'If you have a valid account you will receive an email with instructions to reset your password.', 'Does not include expected message'

  end

end
```

`@response` is a great tool for integration testing without resorting to a Capybara/Selenium setup. If you just want to test that the link is producing something other than a `4xx` code you can just set up an integration test like the ones above under whatever controller contains the link you are testing. Do the applicable `GET/POST` for the link and test the response or `@response.body` for expected behavior.

As mentioned above, this does NOT prove that your mailer is actually sending email, unless your mailer determines the actual webserver response to the link request. I would also set up an actual mailer test in addition to this.